# How to pass loggon user data object with laravel passport token?

Tags: php, angular, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I am new to laravel and angular. I m using Laravel Framework `7.10.2` and Angular `CLI: 8.3.26`
I configured laravel passport according to documentation. Now when user logged in my api sends access token to my angular app.like this(copied from developer console)

```
token:"eyJ0eXAiOixxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

this is my laravel login method.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request){
        $login=$request->validate([
            'email'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required'
        ]);
        if (!Auth::attempt($login)){
            return response(['message'=>'Invalid login details.']);
        }

        $user=Auth::user();
        $token=$user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
        return response(['user'=>Auth::user(),'token'=>$token]);
    }
```

Now I want to save this user id in local storage. But I know it is not secure. So Is it possible to send this user object from this token? 
1)If is it possible how can I do this? 
2)How can I read this(means user object) in the angular application?

This is my angular function to read the token.

```
login() {
    this.authService.login(this.email, this.password).subscribe(res => {
       //reading token comes from api
       console.log(res);
      if (res.token) {
        this.token = res.token;
        localStorage.setItem('auth', this.token);
        this.router.navigate(['tasks'],);

      } else {
        this.errormessage = res.message;
      }
      this.authService.changeProgress(true);
    }, err => {
      this.errormessage='Connection failed! Try again later!';
      this.authService.changeProgress(true);
    });
```

I found some similar questions related to this. But they didn't work for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "So Is it possible to send this user object from this token?" I see that the ``Auth::user()`` object is already returned in ``'user'``.

Comment: but I want to send this object via access token. Not like this. Is it possible? @FaristaLatuconsina

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to store all of this, the passport it self identify whit a user.
In my case I need the username to display in a navbar for that I use a service to get the data, maybe I could store it in the browser but that can be done if that info in the local storage is only for display, not if is an ID or something you need to make a request, that is highly insecure.

So, my advice, is to make a request to get the user info that you need.

I am starting on jwt passport but for what I have read you need the secret key to decode the token, that said I believe you can't decode it on the front-end.

Note: if someone has more info comment please